# Any iPhone master Please tell me the reason for my app crash here is my Log?

Tags: iphone

i am doing Tab application in iPhone with four tabs.
    my app almost completed but while app running some times it is crashing.i observed that issue raising while i am switching between two view's like front and back in navigation.any iPhone master please help me to resolve this?

```
## Log ##  
   Mon Jul 16 21:07:55 unknown MyApp[167] <Warning>: NVVC Dealloc 
    Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2688 (24132):10 
    Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed. 
    Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation 
    fault 
    Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault 
    Mon Jul 16 21:09:04 unknown lockdownd[20] <Error>: (0x403000) handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #7 from Xcode. Killing connection 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55fb]) Exited: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xa13c]) Exited: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.app[0x137]) Exited: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.accessoryd) Exited: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (15%). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'Mail' for 30 seconds. Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'app' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
    Mon Jul 16 22:00:42 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
```

Comment: Whoever edited this last broke the code block.  I reedited.  please review.

Comment: Code block isn't useful here imo, at least now you can read the whole thing at once

Comment: I rather disagree but have it your way.

Comment: What is the message in Console window

Answer (score 0):

This looks familiar:

```
Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

`Segmentation fault` means you're trying to access a memory area you haven't allocated (yet), or in general you're referencing an invalid pointer, I'd double check the relevant parts of code.

Since you're switching views, you might be assuming some memory-related tasks have already been taken care of but in fact they havent'.